# pandas : Abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract methods instantiatedpylint python

Tags: python

I'm using pandas excelWriter to write Excel files. The program runs without any issue, but I'd like to remove this warning.

```py
Abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract methods instantiatedpylint.
```

code:

```
def exportToExcel(df):

    # excell writer
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Top100Triggers.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: `o I'd rather say this is a limitation of pylint, that doesn't / can't introspect objects defining __new__.`
[source](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/pandas-dev/pandas/27634/516027642)

And github issues:
[issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3060)

Comment: Have you found the solution since?

Answer (score 39):

It's a pylint issue that a ticket submited for it ([pylink issue ticket](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3060)) If you feel that it's really annoying, add `# pylint: disable=abstract-class-instantiated` right after writer line line:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Top100Triggers.xlsx') # pylint: disable=abstract-class-instantiated
```

Pylint will temporarily ignore that line.

Answer (score 0):

Although adding `# pylint: disable=abstract-class-instantiated` will disable the alert in this circumstance, below is another "more pythonic" way to deal with this linting issue, ***especially when dealing with "unused" variables***. Replacing the variable with '_'

Example:

```
# excel writer obj
with pd.ExcelWriter('./working_data/managers.xlsx') as writer:
    # key=str obj (managers email), _=dataframe obj (df correlated to manager email)
    for key, _ in man_group: # **note: the _ is used here to avoid a pylint issue**
        # write each grouped object into its own sheet
        man_group.get_group(key).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key, index=False)
```